riscv stack pointer initialization
I am using https://www.qemu.org/docs/master/system/riscv/virt.html to compile some code that prints 'U' out the uart.
My question is about stack initialization. I am assuming I can do this various ways so I have been experimenting as such. AFAIK there is no absolute address given in virt.c stating where I should init the stack pointer. So, I am free to put it wherever after the entry point (0x80000000) within a 128M of ram (declared within the linker script). I am curious about the implementations that don't work (i.e the code compiles but I don't get the output out the uart).
This one works:
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.skip 16384  # 16 KiB
stack_top:

.section .text
.globl _entry
_entry:

    la sp, stack_top 

    # below sets up a stack space for each hart (currently 4 in use)
    li a0, 1024*4
    csrr a1, mhartid
    addi a1, a1, 1
    mul a0, a0, a1
    add sp, sp, a0

    call start

This one works:
.section .bss
.align 16
stack_bottom:
.space 0x80200000-0x80000004
stack_top:

.section .text
.globl _entry
_entry:

    la sp, stack_top 

    # below sets up a stack space for each hart (currently 4 in use)
    li a0, 1024*4
    csrr a1, mhartid
    addi a1, a1, 1
    mul a0, a0, a1
    add sp, sp, a0

    call start

This even works:
.section .text
.globl _entry
_entry:

    auipc sp, 0x0

    # below sets up a stack space for each hart (currently 4 in use)
    li a0, 1024*4
    csrr a1, mhartid
    addi a1, a1, 1
    mul a0, a0, a1
    add sp, sp, a0

    call start

This doesn't work:
.space 0x80200000-0x80000004

.section .text
.globl _entry
_entry:

    lui sp, 0x80200
    addi sp, sp, 0x000

    # below sets up a stack space for each hart (currently 4 in use)
    li a0, 1024*4
    csrr a1, mhartid
    addi a1, a1, 1
    mul a0, a0, a1
    add sp, sp, a0

    call start

I am confused about the one that doesn't work. It is 16 byte aligned looking at the lower 4 hex digits 0000 so I am assuming I have no alignment issues.
Going to assume that disassembly is quite important here, so adding the disassembly for the one that doesn't work and the disassembly to the one that is most similar to the non-working example (the second working example).
Not working disassembly:
0000000080000000 <_entry>:
    80000000:   08020137                lui     sp,0x8020
    80000004:   00010113                mv      sp,sp
    80000008:   00001537                lui     a0,0x1
    8000000c:   f14025f3                csrr    a1,mhartid
    80000010:   00158593                addi    a1,a1,1
    80000014:   02b50533                mul     a0,a0,a1
    80000018:   00a10133                add     sp,sp,a0
    8000001c:   032000ef                jal     8000004e <start>

2nd example disassembly:
0000000080000000 <_entry>:
    80000000:   00210117                auipc   sp,0x210
    80000004:   ffc10113                addi    sp,sp,-4 # 8020fffc <stack_top>
    80000008:   00001537                lui     a0,0x1
    8000000c:   f14025f3                csrr    a1,mhartid
    80000010:   00158593                addi    a1,a1,1
    80000014:   02b50533                mul     a0,a0,a1
    80000018:   00a10133                add     sp,sp,a0
    8000001c:   032000ef                jal     8000004e <start>


Your disassembly comparison should've been a clue... Notice the startling difference in the first command between the two:
80000000:   08020137                lui     sp,0x8020
80000000:   00210117                auipc   sp,0x210

The two commands are quite similar, they both load 20-bit immediate into upper 20 bits of a register. So, if auipc's immediate is 0x210 (resulting in 0x8021'0000) then lui's immediate should be 0x80200 to result in 0x8020'0000. It is however 4 bits short of that so your sp ends up way below ram start!
Interestingly, your original assembly looks right but corresponding disassembly does not.
